# Generalising $I_n=\int_0^1 \arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^n})\mathrm dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

Consider the integrals of the form $$I_n=\int_0^1 \arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^n})\mathrm dx$$

With the help of calculators , I noticed:

$$I_{3}=\frac{3\Gamma{\left(\frac{11}{6}\right)}}{5\Gamma{\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}}\sqrt{π}$$

$$I_{5}=\frac{5\Gamma{\left(\frac{17}{10}\right)}}{7\Gamma{\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)}}\sqrt{π}$$

$$I_{7}=\frac{7\Gamma{\left(\frac{23}{14}\right)}}{9\Gamma{\left(\frac{8}{7}\right)}}\sqrt{π}$$

$$I_{13}=\frac{13\Gamma{\left(\frac{41}{26}\right)}}{15\Gamma{\left(\frac{14}{13}\right)}}\sqrt{π}$$

So , based on the pattern, I thought that if $n$ is a positive integer greater than $3$, then :

$$I_{n}=\frac{n\Gamma{\left(\frac{3n+2}{2n}\right)}}{(n+2)\Gamma{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}}\sqrt{π}$$

**Question:**

How can we prove the above generalisation ? Can we extend it for even larger set of numbers ?

Comment: Integrate by parts. Then a change of variable should lead to a beta function.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut By considering (1) as a function ? Thanks

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One integration by parts leads to
$$\int\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^n}\right)\,dx=x\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^n}\right)+$$
$$\frac{n }{n+2}\,x \sqrt{x^n}\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{n}+\frac
   {3}{2};x^n\right)$$

$$I_n=\int_0^1\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^n}\right)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{2\, \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$ For large $n$
$$I_n=\frac \pi 2\left(1-\frac{2\log (2)}{n}+\frac{\pi ^2+12 \log ^2(2)}{6 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$

$n$ does not need to be an integer.

Comment: $\frac{n }{n+2}\,x \sqrt{x^n}\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{n}+\frac
   {3}{2};x^n\right)$ . I lost it right there  But thanks !

Comment: @An_Elephant. You can use any value of $n$ (not an integer works).

Comment: I meant that I don't know what $F$ means ?

Comment: @An_Elephant. Sorry ! It is the Gaussian hypergeometric function

Comment: Thanks ! Claude sir . I hope to learn these mathematics soon.

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $$x = \sin^{2 / n} \theta, \qquad dx = \frac{\sin^{2 / n} \theta \cos \theta \,d\theta}{n \sin \theta}$$
transforms the integral to
$$\frac{1}{n} \int_0^{\pi / 2} \underbrace{(\pi - 2 \theta)}_u \,\underbrace{\sin^{(2 - n) / n} \theta \, \cos \theta \,d\theta}_{dv} .$$
Applying integration by parts with $u, dv$ as indicated gives
$$\int_0^{\pi / 2} \sin^{2 / n} \theta \,d\theta = \mathrm{B}\left(\frac12 + \frac1n, \frac12\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12 + \frac1n\right) \Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(1 + \frac1n\right)} = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt\pi \,\Gamma\left(\frac12 + \frac1n\right)}{\Gamma\left(1 + \frac1n\right)}} ,$$
where $\mathrm{B}$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).
We can see that this lattermost expression is equivalent to yours by taking $z = \frac12 + \frac1n$ in the Gamma function identity $\Gamma(z + 1) = z \Gamma(z)$. (We assume $n > 0$; if $n = 0$ the original integrand is identically zero, and if $n < 0$ the original integral is not defined.)